# Removing the splash screen on shutdown an startup. I want to be able to see the processes

Tags: xubuntu, screen, plymouth

I know this has been asked but on slightly different terms. I would like to remove it so that I can see the code behind. Not one off but every time it is shutdown and started.
Thaknk you in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I recommend just editing your `/etc/default/grub`.

Change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

Remember to update grub afterward with `sudo update-grub` at the command line.

**Comment**:  Originally, I put `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`.  Note this will end your boot process at the command line.  After (possibly) having to login with username and password, `startx` at the prompt will start up your usual GUI.

Comment: This made my Ubuntu loose all the x GUI not the splash.

Comment: @Luke I'm glad it helped.  I hope you didn't run into a problem like the others.  See my revised answer.

Comment: @erdemkeren See my edited answer if you need to get back into the GUI.  Alternatively, you can edit your grub again using the `nano` editor, which is a friendly console-based editor.

Comment: No problem about recovering. Just wanted to inform others. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 7):

For a single boot process, you can interrupt Grub <kbd>e</kbd> (edit), move the cursor to the kernel you want to start, <kbd>e</kbd> edit the line with the kernel and remove the

```
splash quiet
```

or change them to

```
nosplash noquiet
```

A persistent solution would be to modify your /boot/grub/menu.lst file from:

```
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-39-generic root=UUID=01-cafe ro quiet splash locale=de_DE
```

to:

```
kernel      /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-39-generic root=UUID=01-cafe ro locale=de_DE
```

(your locale might vary). After installing a new kernel, the new one will again have the default settings. Modify in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noquiet nosplash"
```

if you have such a file. See

```
info grub
```

on how to change your grub settings in general. There is a graphical customize for grub: https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer but I haven't tested it.

Comment: `menu.lst` is gone a very long time ago...

Comment: @enzotib: menu.lst is present in 10.04, the current LTS version of (X/K)ubuntu. It isn't gone, and it isn't gone long ago.

Comment: @userunknown: from [Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2): "GRUB 2 is the default boot loader and manager for Ubuntu since version 9.10 (Karmic Koala)". Maybe *you* have chosen to stay with grub legacy.

Comment: @enzotib: Afaik, with Grub2 the way the menu.lst file is modified has changed, but the file is still in use. I'm always updating my Linux installation and my /etc/grub.d dir is from 4.2010. The `20_memtest86+` file therein contains the note: `older versions of grub2 do not have this yet (LP: #459080)` so my impression is, that I'm using a kind of grub2. /etc/grub.d wasn't there with the former grub.