# How to set a text theme for plymouth?

Tags: 12.04, plymouth

I have Ubuntu 12.04 (beta) and I want to set a text theme for Plymouth, because I need to read what commands the PC is running on shutdown (because it freezes when I shutdown it), but the method I found googling ( [How do I change the plymouth bootscreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen) ) is not working: this is the ouput of `update-alternatives --list default.plymouth`:

```
user@host:~$ update-alternatives --list default.plymouth
/lib/plymouth/themes/solar/solar.plymouth
/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth
user@host:~$
```

And the text themes are not displayed. How can I set a text theme for Plymouth?

Comment: I already have another theme (plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text), anyway it doesn't work installing another theme either

Comment: What is a "text theme" for Plymouth?  My understanding is that Plymouth provides a splash screen so as to *hide* the booting-up text.  If you don't want the splash screen, you have to turn off the Plymouth splash, *not* install another theme.

Comment: I think what you're really asking is this:  http://askubuntu.com/q/120898/43660

Comment: Oh, yes, this is acceptable :) so what is the utility of the plymouth text themes, if they do not enable a text boot?

Comment: Actually, now I remember what you're talking about.  The text themes are just cruddier versions of the splash screens.  When there is a graphics problem, plymouth will revert to showing a text version of the logo and the progress bar (dots appearing).

Comment: I remember plymouth text themes, I saw them on Fedora a couple of years ago, they are nice and are a good compromise between text boot and splash boot IMHO... it's a pity that text themes cannot be activated manually

Comment: Also, I remember that using `plymouth-set-default-theme --list` I was able to choose plymouth text theme... there must be a way to enable it now!

Comment: Some time has passed and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS has been released as stable. After updating, do you find you still need help with this issue? (I would think yes, given the nature of the problem, but I figure it's still worthwhile to check.)

Comment: I resolved disabling plymouth, but I could not set the plymouth text theme, so yes, it remains unresolved

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth 10
```

and then

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to select the splash theme:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

And use the following to select the text-theme:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config text.plymouth
```

Comment: No, Plymouth text theme is still missing from the list of avialable plymouth themes (also in 12.10 Quantic Quetzal)

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `sudo update-alternatives --list text.plymouth`?
Also, what is the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`?

Answer (score 0):

Appears to have changed to

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

[image]

Comment: Seeing that you installed solar I installed the solar theme and it appears in the choices... but not the text themes, that are the ones I need :( I edit the question